# Delphi Excel UDF with Variant return Type

Tags: excel, delphi, udf

I have an add-in that registers UDFs using ExecuteExcel4Macro.  this is working fine.  The add-in only registers when it detects a compatible workbook in the current session.

The problem is I want to change the current UDF from returning just a char but a char or an excel error.

I found some articles about using the Type library but I believe that means my UDF will always be registered and I want to control when I register them.

I currently Register with

```
ExcelApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro('REGISTER("filepath","add-in-name","AccountDescription","CC","Account Id","My Addin group")');

function AccountDescription ( sAccountId: PChar ) : PChar ; stdcall ;
```

I am using add-in-express to help with excel automation.
The CC indicates that the function accepts a null terminated string and expects a null terminated string returned.  I am not sure if I can specify a variant so I can return Excel2000.xlErrNa.

Edit: Fixed function call above I forgot REGISTER.

Edit (2):
The 4th parameter in the register function contains the udf parameter and return value types.  I'm not sure how to indicate a variant.

Edit (3):
The dll / project is called DynacViews2 and in the DynacViews2.dll source file there is :

```
exports AccountDescription;
```

Sorry if this is a little fragmented.  I want to emphasis that this is working with the code above currently.  The issue is trying to get change the signature of AccountDescription to return an OleVariant instead of a PChar.

The reason for the change is I want to return a string or an Excel Error.  Other examples online including add-in-express, show using the TypeLibrary to add the function and specify the return type as variant. This creates a signature using OleVariant and a string or Excel Error(Excel2000.xlErrNa) can be returned.  The problem is I am using the VBA REGISTER function to only add the UDF's if the workbook is compatible.

I may be tackling this problem incorrectly.

Edit 4:
[Example of Register usage](http://www.codematic.net/excel-development/excel-xll/excel-xll-register.htm) - This link shows the register usage but doesn't link to any microsoft site so there is no explanation of how to specify the parameters.

Comment: google "delphi deborah pate excel udf"  It should find an old post of hers (she was a Borland TeamB member" that showed how to write a UDF in Delphi without using Add-In Express"

Comment: @alex I didn't find much.  Add-in-express is just a tool to make using excel easier.  I am using the REGISTER function to help with managing if a UDF is register.

Comment: There's no [Mcve] which dosant help. What do add in express support say. They are excellent.

Comment: Them perhaps you missed her post in this thread: v=http://www.delphigroups.info/2/48/258279.html  it's the one date-stamped Sun, 03 Jul 2005 00:13:20 GMT.  I know what Add-In Express is, btw.

Comment: @alex the post refers to an xla file. Looking for help with the Excel Register function.

Comment: @david It is not add-in-express functionality I need help with it is the Excel Register Function and for the life of me I cannot get google to find the documentation on it.  I know it is there I have seen it before.  It also has a table that explains what parameters type to pass it.  It is possible what I am trying to do is not allowed.

Comment: btw, I did have an incomplete example.  I have fixed the code example above.  Hopefully it is more complete now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm sure I had some help from the registering a udf. I thought they had some wrapping of that. I also can't see your udf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added an extra line with the signature of the UDF.  I'll give add-in-express a try.  The 4th parameter in the REGISTER function contains the parameter types and the return type.

Comment: I don't see how you can return a pointer. Who's going to tidy up. Anyway, I also don't see how the VBA is going to see your function. Where will it look for it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added a little more detail.  Hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: Er why XLM and excel 4. Doesn't that predate VBA and variants and com and so on. If I were you I'd try to do it the modern way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is inherited code and I might have to understand the modern way of doing it.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that my rambling contribution here is worthy of that.

Comment: You don't have to add *Edit* in the text every time you update the question. The [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41106040/revisions) tracks that automatically.

Comment: Ya, but it helped me when others did that when I was reading comments. You read a comment and look up and see what was changed instead of having to go look somewhere.  Otherwise the initial comments don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Using the CALL and Register Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-CALL-and-REGISTER-functions-06FA83C1-2869-4A89-B665-7E63D188307F), Variant is not among the supported data types.

```
Code  Description                            Pass by               C Declaration
A     Logical (FALSE = 0), TRUE = 1)         Value                 short int
B     IEEE 8-byte floating-point number      Value (Windows)       double (Windows)
                                             Reference (Macintosh) double * (Macintosh)
C     Null-terminated string                 Reference             char *
      (maximum length=255)
D     Byte-counted string (first byte        Reference             Unsigned char *
      contains length of string, maximum 
      string length = 255 characters)
E     IEEE 8-byte floating-point number      Reference             double *
F     Null-terminated string (maximum        Reference (modify     char *
      string length = 255 characters)        in place)
G     Byte-counted string (first byte        Reference (modify
      contains length of string, maximum     in place)             unsigned char *
      string length = 255 characters)
H     Unsigned 2-byte integer                Value                 unsigned short int
I     Signed 2-byte integer                  Value                 short int
J     Signed 4-byte integer                  Value                 long int
K     Array                                  Reference             FP *
L     Logical (FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1)          Reference             short int *
M     Signed 2-byte integer                  Reference             short int *
N     Signed 4-byte integer                  Reference             long int *
O     Array                                  Reference             Three arguments are 
                                                                   passed:
                                                                   unsigned short int *
                                                                   unsigned short int *
                                                                   double [ ]
P     Microsoft Excel OPER data structure    Reference             OPER *
R     Microsoft Excel XLOPER data structure  Reference             XLOPER *
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I saw that table before but after a day of googling I couldn't find it again.